# How do you use an identity file with rsync?

Tags: unix, rsa, rsync, dsa

#### How do you use an identity file with rsync?

This is the syntax I *think* I should be using with rsync to use an identity file to connect:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p1234  -i ~/.ssh/1234-identity'  \
"/local/dir/" remoteUser@22.33.44.55:"/remote/dir/"
```

But it's giving me an error:

```
Warning: Identity file ~/.ssh/1234-identity not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

The file is fine, permissions are set correctly, it works when doing ssh - just not with rsync - at least in my syntax. What am I doing wrong? Is it trying to look for the identity file on the remote machine? If so, how do I specify that I want to use an identity file on my *local* machine?

Comment: Seems to work OK now with rsync 3.1.2 ...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You may want to use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to load the key into memory.  `ssh` will try identities from ssh-agent automatically if it can find them. Commands would be

```
eval $(ssh-agent) # Create agent and environment variables
ssh-add ~/.ssh/1234-identity
```

`ssh-agent` is a user daemon which holds unencrypted ssh keys in memory.  ssh finds it based on environment variables which ssh-agent outputs when run.  Using `eval` to evaluate this output creates the environment variables.  `ssh-add` is the command which manages the keys memory.  The agent can be locked using ssh-add.  A default lifetime for a key can be specified when ssh-agent is started, and or specified for a key when it is added.

You might also want to setup a ~/.ssh/config file to supply the port and key definition. (See `man ssh_config for more options.)

```
host 22.33.44.55
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/1234-identity
    Port 1234
```

Single quoting the ssh command will prevent shell expansion which is needed for `~` or `$HOME`.  You could use the full or relative path to the key in single quotes.

Comment: Double quotes and using $HOME solved my problem. Can you elaborate on what the first two commands are doing? I was already familiar with setting up a config file - the only problem is when I have multiple accounts on one server. I don't expect that it would let me specify multiple identity files for the same host.

Comment: +1 This fixed my issue with drone.io :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is friggin' awesome. FTR, you can also specify the default username to connect as, e.g. `User ubuntu` when configuring for an EC2 Ubuntu instance :) Thanks!

Comment: If you're using csh style shell (such as `fish`) then do `eval (ssh-agent -c)`

Answer (score 106):

Use either `$HOME`

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p1234  -i \"$HOME/.ssh/1234-identity\"" dir remoteUser@server:
```

or full path to the key:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p1234  -i /home/username/.ssh/1234-identity" dir user@server:
```

Tested with rsync 3.0.9 on Ubuntu

Comment: Yes this works fine, no need to use ssh-agent or other config options.

Comment: +1: this is a globbing issue, just like you couldn't do "ls '~'"

Comment: `$HOME` will not work inside simple quotes (no variable expansion), so you must either use double quotes or the absolute path.

Comment: in standard Bash should work `"$HOME"` or `$HOME` without any difference (also `"${HOME}"` is possible, if you want to make it complicated)

Comment: I've changed the single quotes to doubles.

Comment: @Tombart `$HOME` without quotes would be a problem if it contains whitespace.

Answer (score 36):

You have to specify the absolute path to your identity key file. This probably some sort of quirck in rsync. (it can't be perfect after all)

I ran into this issue just a few days ago :-)

Comment: You can use ~ but you can't embed it within single quotes, because then it doesn't get substituted correctly to /home/username/ you must use double quotes to have correct that work correctly, see @ilcavero 's solution

Answer (score 26):

This works for me

```
rsync -avz --rsh="ssh -p1234  -i ~/.ssh/1234-identity"  \
"/local/dir/" remoteUser@22.33.44.55:"/remote/dir/"
```

Comment: For some reason I had to specify full path to the identity file, i.e. `/home/user/.ssh/1234-identity`. Then it worked. Possibly because it's then a different shell, as suggested in Darhuuk 's answer.

Comment: @osa you saved me there! I was having an issue with Drupal and rSYNC and the issue was the path...weird.

Answer (score 11):

use key file with rsync:

```
rsync -rave "ssh -i /home/test/pkey_new.pem" /var/www/test/ ubuntu@231.210.24.48:/var/www/test
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you executing the command in bash or sh? This might make a difference. Try replacing `~` with `$HOME`. Try double-quoting the string for the `-e` option.