# rsync folder from amazon instance to local linux desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, rsync

I want to rync my folders which are in amazon instance to my linux pc on network. 
I tried following but it gives me error as I know that I have done some syntax mistake..

```
rsync -avPn "ssh -i /keys/mykey.pem ec2-user@X.X.X.X:/data/" /data/
```

Pls help me to improve my comand.

Error:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/root//ssh -i /keys/mykey.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x:/data/" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 12 bytes  received 12 bytes  48.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1072) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your `ssh-agent` to store SSH Keys and then add `mykey.pem` to your SSH agent before using rsync. Further, you could simply use the syntax:

`rsync -avPn ec2-user@X.X.X.X:/data/ /data/`

This SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527068/how-do-you-use-an-identity-file-with-rsync) talks about a similar problem. Hope this helps.

P.S.: It would be great if you could support your question with error message(s) if any, that would help everyone identify the exact problem and provide efficient solutions.