# Transfer function that saves progress?

Tags: unix, copy, scp

Does a function exist similar to `scp` where if the connection is lost, then the progress is saved, and resuming the process picks up where it left off? I am trying to `scp` a large file, and my VPN connection keeps cutting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rsync --partial`. It will keep partially transferred files, which you can then resume with the same invocation. From the rsync man page:

> --partial
>                 By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances  it  is
>                 more  desirable to keep partially transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file which
>                 should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

Try something like `rsync -aivz --partial user@host:/path/to/file ~/destination/folder/`

Explanation of the other switches:

- `a` — "archive mode": make transfer recursive; preserve symlinks, permissions, timestamps, group, owner; and (where possible) preserve special and device files
- `i` — "itemize changes": shows you what exactly is getting changed (it will be a string of all + signs if you're copying a file anew `+++++++`)
- `v` — "verbose": list files as they're transferred
- `z` — "zip": compress data during transfer

Those are just the ones I usually use to transfer files. You can see a list of all options by looking at the `rsync` man page.

Comment: What does the `-aivz` option do?

Comment: One additional question. I am doing this from AWS and usually use `scp -i <public key>`. Can I do that with `rsync`?

Comment: (I updated my answer with an explanation of the other flags.) Apropos of using an identity file, it looks like someone asked a question about something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527068/how-do-you-use-an-identity-file-with-rsync#5527157  I use ssh-add frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and additional reference