# How to use identity files with rsync and a tunnel?

Tags: unix, rsync

I want to rsync data to a remote computer, but I have to go through a tunnel.
The following works already:

```
rsync -rvl -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -J user@login.company.com" /home/data/  user@computer42:/home/data/
```

However, I have to enter two passwords each time.

Above I tried to pass an identity file, as suggested in [How do you use an identity file with rsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527068).
However, I still get a request for the first password (while there is no error message).

Also I would like to how to pass the second identity file to overcome the second password request?

Answer (score 1):

First of all be sure you have your public key on both servers and that is working.
and by working I mean if you ssh to both of them without a password

Then I would open an ssh tunnel first then connect to the tunnel, its a bit easier to debug if needed

```
ssh -L 2224:computer42:22 user@login.company.com -N &
rsync -arpve "ssh -p 2224" /home/data/ user@computer42:/home/data/
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a password prompt for the first login `user@login.company.com` because you are not providing any identity file for this login. Assuming you have already setup password-less SSH to this host (`login.company.com`) OR it's identity file to be at `/path/to/login_company.pem`, you can follow the following steps.

I am using SSH-config file (usually at `~/.ssh/config`) to simplify the `rsync` command.

```
host final_destination
    HostName computer42
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -vvvv jump_host

host jump_host        
    HostName login.company.com
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/path/to/login_company.pem
```

At this point, following command should work without any password prompts and should take you to the host `computer42` as user `user`.

```
ssh final_destination
```

Once this works, your `rsync` command becomes as simple as this;

```
rsync -az -vvvv /path/to/local/file final_destination:/path/to/destination -e "ssh"
```

PS:

The command that you provide as part of `-e` is being used to connect to the destination host. Since we are using SSH config-files, all we need to do now is to delegate the SSH connection setup to the `ssh` command. Everything required to reach the hosts is already configured in the config file.
In contrast to the approach that you are taking, where you are configuring everything in line, the final command becomes

```
ssh -vvvv -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -J user@login.company.com user@computer42
```

and if you run this command on your CLI, you'd get a password prompt which is the way `rsync` is behaving as well.

TIP:
Moreover, you should run the SSH commands with `-vvvv` flag to print verbose output.